# Graphical way to install .flatpakref (Flatpak) files?

Tags: software-installation, flatpak, monodevelop

I've been downloaded a file from MonoDevelop website but it couldn't execute in my ubuntu, how to open that file?

filename is "monodevelop.flatpakref"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 14.04

Based on [burhanuddin abbas'](https://askubuntu.com/users/622500/burhanuddin-abbas) [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883901/graphical-way-to-install-flatpakref-flatpak-files/1002418#comment1627298_1002418) there's a problem on Ubuntu 14.04.

> Unable to locate package flatpak , because it is not supported for ubuntu 14.04 . Visit [here](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/956) for more details

#### Newer Ubuntu versions (tested on 16.04)

1. Installation of `flatpak`

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install flatpak
   ```

   1. (Optional) Adding the `flathub` repository

      ```
      flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
      ```
2. Installation of MonoDevelop with `flatpakref` file

   ```
   flatpak install monodevelop.flatpakref
   ```
3. Running the application

   ```
   flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop
   ```

   (probably, not tested, based on [@purlantov answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/886017/830570)).

---

Source: [OMG! Ubuntu: 7 Flatpak Apps You Can Install Right Now from Flathub](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/7-flatpak-apps-can-install-right-now-flathub).

Answer (score 2):

A graphical way to install Flatpak app using .flatpakref file starts with installing flatpak plugin to add flatpak support into default software center.

For Debian-based GNOME desktop,

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

For Debian-based KDE desktop,

```
sudo apt install plasma-discover-plugin-flatpak
```

You can change the package manager based on your supported Linux distro. However, most Linux distro comes with pre-configured support for Flatpak.

Now if you search for app in your software center, you'll notice two application one with source pointing to flathub repo i.e. flatpak app.

Nonetheless, if you've already downloaded the .flatpakref file, it's better to run a single command to install a flatpak app.

```
flatpak install --from <app-id>.flatpakref
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very helpfull:
[Install MonoDevelop preview via FlatPak](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/)

It worked for me but any time that you want to start MonoDevelop you have to type in console:

```
flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop
```

And there is lot of things that do not work properly.
I suggest you to compile it yourself as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dp0LjLh5F8c),
which helped me a lot.

Unfortunately there are no longer pre-compiled packages for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Now I think you can Graphical install Flatpak. It now prompts to a new dialog box to install:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) or later

As the [documentation](https://flathub.org/setup/Ubuntu) suggests, run:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

then Install the Software Flatpak plugin:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

Possibly install the Flathub repo:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

and restart.